# Deleting and Updating Dictionary key/value through user input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

Hello i'm trying to play around with python dictionaries i was able to create a dictionary through user input but i can't find a way to update and delete a dictionary by taking a user input.

```
dictionary = {}
ele = int(input("How many element u want? "))

for i in range(ele):
    inn = input("Key: ")
    nam = input("Value: ")
    dictionary.update({inn:nam})

print(dictionary)
```

this is my code to create a dictionary through user input now i need help with deleting and updating a dictionary through user input if possible.

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean by deleting and updating   `dictionary`

Comment: well for example i have a dictionary e.g. dic = {"fruit":"Apple"} and i want to update the "Apple" value so how will i do that?

Comment: You can use the `dictionary['fruit'] = 'Some_name'` to achieve this

Comment: Thanks,but i know how to do that i'm trying update the dictionary value dynamically like through user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"deleting" dictionary:

```
dictionary = {1:"hi"}
delete = input("do you want to delete the contents of the dictionary? (y/n").lower()
if delete in ["y","yes"]: dictionary = {}
```

making this a bit more compact:

```
dictionary = {1:"hi"}
if input("do you want to delete the contents of the dictionary? (y/n): ").lower() in ["y","yes"]: dictionary = {}
print(dictionary)

>> do you want to delete the contents of the dictionary? (y/n): y

>> {}
```

explanation:

using the input function (as i believe you know about) transformed the input to lowercase and then checked if it was in a list of acceptable answers.
`dictionary = {}` sets the dictionary back to containing nothing

---

updating dictionary:

```
def updateDict(dictionary):
    choice = int(input("do you want to (1) add/update an item to the dictionary or (2) remove an item: (1 or 2):  "))
    if choice in [1,2]:
        if choice == 1:
            dictionary[input("key: ")] = input("value: ")
        else:
            dictionary.pop(input("key: "))
    else:
        print("invalid choice")
```

Keep in mind: this only adds string values, you can always add a choice to specify what data type is being entered.

Comment: Thank! yeah i wnna know how to update a dictionary too through user input.

Comment: @k.joe so just adding/deleting items?

Comment: yeah for now it's just deleting and updating dictionary items.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the dictionary you just redefine it as empty

```
dictionary = {}
```

For deleting an item from a dictionary use

```
del dictionary[key]
```

To update a value you can use

```
dictionary[key] = value
```

You can set the key as a variable that the user inputs to select the key to be deleted or updated.